# Marker position not updating

Tags: android

I am new to Android.I am using many hardcoded latitude and longitude for android map.I have stored the latitude and longitude in an arraylist.There are two markers-Bus and Student.I have to drag Bus marker  to the latitude longitude position after every 10 sec and should remain at the last postion but my marker is not updating to the position.

```
public class TransportBusMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap map;
  // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 100 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 10000; // 10 sec
LatLngBounds.Builder builder;
CameraUpdate cu;
int count=0;

ArrayList<LatLng> locations = new ArrayList();
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.transport_bus_map);
    locations.add(new LatLng(28.6311812, 77.3785497));
    locations.add(new LatLng(28.6310870, 77.3796440));
    locations.add(new LatLng(28.631012, 77.3805697));
    locations.add(new LatLng(28.627462, 77.3838835));
    locations.add(new LatLng(28.631107, 77.384071));

            /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     **/
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map=googleMap;
    /**clear the map before redraw to them*/
    map.clear();
    /**Create dummy Markers List*/
     List<Marker> markersList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    //if(locations!=null)
  final Marker Bus = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(28.6311812, 77.3785497)).title("Bus"));
    Marker Student = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
            28.631107, 77.384071)).title("Student"));

    markersList.add(Bus);

    final Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                      @Override
                      public void run() {

                          for (int i = 0; i <locations.size(); i++) {
                                                     LatLng currentPosition = locations.get(i);
                              Bus.setPosition(currentPosition);
                              CameraUpdate mLoc = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder().target(currentPosition).build());
                              map.moveCamera(mLoc);
                                                                  h.postDelayed(this, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES);

                      }}
                  },MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES);


            markersList.add(Student);

    /**create for loop for get the latLngbuilder from the marker list*/
    builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker m : markersList) {
        builder.include(m.getPosition());
    }
    /**initialize the padding for map boundary*/
    int padding = 50;
    /**create the bounds from latlngBuilder to set into map camera*/
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    /**create the camera with bounds and padding to set into map*/
    cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);

    /**call the map call back to know map is loaded or not*/

    map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            /**set animated zoom camera into map*/
            map.animateCamera(cu);
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Can you explain your need in brief?

Comment: I want to update marker Bus according to the latitude,longitude in arraylist

Comment: I think you should have to show markers on all point which can be listed in your question right?

Comment: Yes.I want to drag marker between locations and should change locations after every 10 sec

Comment: Your Question confliction is to much. Due to your explanation. because first u r saying that u need multiple marker on all listed LatLng in your question but than after that u are saying that u need the location after every 10 seconds than there is no need to put multiple marker just put single marker and try to get location continuesly that's it.

Comment: There are already two markers and i want to move only marker bus to be updated on LatLng

Comment: Ok now i understand which kind of help does u need.